# What is the difference between a uppercase letter and a lower case letter denoting a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose, we have x = [10,20], and the matrix is denoted by a lowercase x. 
So now, what does an uppercase X stand for?

Comment: It doesn't stand for anything since you haven't define it yet.

Comment: vectors are usually lowercase

Comment: ^yeah, and for example if you have an vector y, the components could be noted y1 and y2.... etc just convention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in the end, it's up to you!

Normally, vectors are noted with lower case letters, while matrices in general are noted with upper case letters.

Your matrix $x$ is a vector, since $x^{T}$ only has one column, so it fits conventional standards.